# Showing take pictures and videos permission without using camera permission

Tags: android

when I want to install my apk, my smart-phone shows this page :

[image]

inside my module, I never used any `android.permission.CAMERA` permission.

all my `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="*.*.*.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Are you using any libraries that are declaring this permission in their Manifest files?

Comment: there is any way to remove this permission ?

Comment: Well, looks you've got your answer.

Comment: Yes, by removing the library from your project.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html